# How to Access Password/SSL Secured Content through YQL and Yahoo Pipes

Tags: https, yql, yahoo-pipes, http-status-code-401

The content is secured through basic HTTP authentication: you try to access the URL, you're prompted for user pass by your browser, fill submit, and bam you've gotten the resource. These steps can all be condensed by making a request as follows in a normal browser:

```
http://user:password@host.tld/somethingsnazzy.xml
```

For HTTP/FTP I've seed simple fetches in Pipes retrieve password protected feeds using a url. The [Get Password Protected Feed](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=e9eb03e3173dfa7dce69bee0c589a619) pipe is one example.

Yahoo Pipes, however, does not support SSL... so while I could make a request like `https://user:password@host.tld/somethingsnazzy.xml` from my browser, the pipe will fail. A work around involves using YQL to access the protected resource since it does support HTTPS:

```
select * from xml where url='https://host.tld/notpassswordbutstillsnazzy.xml'
```

While a statement like the one above works fine, making a secured HTTP request that includes a username and password still yeilds a 401 error:

```
select * from rss where url='https://user:password@host.tld/somethingsnazzy.xml'
```

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this query](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=USE%20%27https%3A//gist.github.com/raw/2248475/c84ca7a88267f0f7c713129873ef86457b40e67b/httpbasicaccess.xml%27%20AS%20remote%3B%20SELECT%20%2a%20FROM%20remote%20WHERE%20url%3D%27https%3A//host.tld/notpassswordbutstillsnazzy.xml%27%20AND%20username%20%3D%20%27user%27%20AND%20password%3D%27password%27%3B).

It uses an Open Data Table at https://gist.github.com/2248475

Comment: Close. The 401 error results the server requires a specific authentication method. In my case an HTTP digest was required for authentication as opposed to basic authentication which your XML provides. After dabbling with some javascript, I managed to get it working.